# Where do I import `PlaceResult` from in `@agm/core`

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm converting an existing application from Angular 5 to Angular 6 and TypeScript 2.9.2 and the compiler is complaining that it doesn't like:-

```
import { } from 'googlemaps';
```

so I changed it to:-

```
import { google } from “@agm/core/services/google-maps-types”;
```

so a statement like:-

```
const autocomplete = new google.maps.palces.Autocompete(…);
```

works. But when I use this:-

```
const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

and I get an error saying:-

```
Cannot find namespace ‘google'
```

I want to change that to:-

```
const place: PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

but I can figure out how to import `PlaceResult`.

Where do I import `PlaceResult` from? Is this the right approach or is there some other way?

I’m using the latest versions of `@types/googlemaps@3.37.7` and `@agm/core@1.0.0` and `Angular 6.1.10`.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?